# CASE WHEN to assign a result set to a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've been trying to assign different resultsets to a query depending on an input

Depending on the company selected a set of filtered results should be displayed, here's my code.

```
DECLARE @COMPANY VARCHAR(10) = 'Company_name1'

SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN @COMPANY = 'Company_name1'
           THEN (SELECT INVENTLOCATIONID FROM INVENTDIM INV 
                 WHERE (INV.DATAAREAID = @COMPANY) 
                   AND (((INVENTLOCATIONID IS NOT NULL) 
                   AND ((WMSLOCATIONID IS NOT NULL) 
                   AND (WMSLOCATIONID <> '')))
                   AND (INV.INVENTLOCATIONID = 'x5'))
        WHEN @COMPANY = 'Company_name2'
           THEN (SELECT INVENTLOCATIONID FROM INVENTDIM INV 
                 WHERE (INV.DATAAREAID = @COMPANY) 
                   AND (((INVENTLOCATIONID IS NOT NULL)
                   AND ((WMSLOCATIONID IS NOT NULL)
                   AND (WMSLOCATIONID <> '')))
                   AND (INVENTLOCATIONID IN ('X0', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X5', 'X6', 'X8', 'P6', 'P8')))
           ELSE (SELECT INVENTLOCATIONID FROM INVENTDIM INV 
                 WHERE (DATAAREAID = @COMPANY) 
                   AND ((INVENTLOCATIONID IS NOT NULL) 
                   AND ((WMSLOCATIONID IS NOT NULL) 
                   AND (WMSLOCATIONID <> '')))
      END) AS WHAREWOUSE
FROM 
    INVENTDIM INV 
ORDER BY 
    INV.INVENTLOCATIONID
```

Why am I not allowed to do this?

Comment: `CASE` is an _expression_ that returns exactly one scalar result. It can't be used for control of flow like an `IF` statement. Maybe with `TOP (1)` in the subquery, but that's awful, and I feel like there is a simpler way to accomplish what you're after with one simple join, but you'll have better luck if you set up sample data and desired results using a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019).

Comment: Can you create a new cross reference table to allow the database to map company to the inventlocationid?

Comment: Another time, you can find a large amount of relevant information in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which would have gone a long way towards answering your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you could do this using a `CASE` expression. Use a constant to *reject* entries where the company name matches the specific cases and the location is *not* in your list. If the company isn't one of the special cases, then accept it.

```
DECLARE @COMPANY VARCHAR(10) = 'Company_name1';

SELECT WHAREHOUSE = INVENTLOCATIONID
FROM dbo.INVENTDIM
  WHERE DATAAREAID = @COMPANY
  AND INVENTLOCATIONID IS NOT NULL
  AND WMSLOCATIONID IS NOT NULL
  AND WMSLOCATIONID <> ''
AND 1 = 
(
    CASE 
      WHEN DATAAREAID = 'Company_name1' 
           AND INVENTLOCATIONID <> 'x5' 
           THEN 0
      WHEN DATAAREAID = 'Company_name2' 
           AND INVENTLOCATIONID NOT IN ('X0','X1','X2','X3','X5','X6','X8','P6','P8') 
           THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END
)
ORDER BY INVENTLOCATIONID;
```

Potentially a disaster for query plan reuse, though, unless `DATAAREAID` is unique.

[This is definitely a better approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63676728/i-want-a-case-when-to-assign-a-result-set-to-a-query/63677194#comment112602171_63676728):

> Can you create a new cross reference table to allow the database to map company to the inventlocationid? – Zynon Putney II

So say you had a mapping table like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.LocationMap
(
  DATAAREAID varchar(10),
  INVENTLOCATIONID char(2),
  PRIMARY KEY(DATAAREAID, INVENTLOCATIONID
);

INSERT dbo.LocationMap(DATAAREAID,INVENTLOCATIONID)
VALUES
('Company_Name1', 'x5'),
('Company_Name2', 'X0'), ('Company_Name2', 'X1') -- , ...
```

Then your query becomes:

```
DECLARE @COMPANY VARCHAR(10) = 'Company_name1';

SELECT WHAREHOUSE = INV.INVENTLOCATIONID
FROM dbo.INVENTDIM AS INV
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.LocationMap AS lm
  ON INV.DATAAREAID = lm.DATAAREAID
WHERE INV.DATAAREAID = @COMPANY
      AND INV.INVENTLOCATIONID IS NOT NULL
      AND INV.WMSLOCATIONID IS NOT NULL
      AND INV.WMSLOCATIONID <> ''
      AND (lm.INVENTLOCATIONID = INV.INVENTLOCATIONID
           OR lm.DATAAREAID IS NULL)
ORDER BY INV.INVENTLOCATIONID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Written as a single query this is equivalent logic. Depending on the size of your data it's possible that the `if..else` branching would work better.

```
SELECT INVENTLOCATINID
FROM INVENTDIM INV
WHERE 
    INV.DATAAREAID = @COMPANY AND INVENTLOCATIONID IS NOT NULL WMSLOCATIONID <> '' AND
    (
        @COMPANY = 'Company name1' AND INV.INVENTLOCATIONID = 'x5' OR
        @COMPANY = 'Company_name2' AND INVENTLOCATIONID IN
            ('X0', 'X1','X2','X3','X5','X6','X8','P6','P8') OR
        @COMPANY NOT IN ('Company name1', 'Company name2')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below query to get desired output

```
DECLARE @COMPANY VARCHAR(10) = 'Company_name1'

declare @tblIL as table
(
INVENTLOCATIONID int
)

IF(@COMPANY = 'Company_name1')
BEGIN
    insert into @tblIL(INVENTLOCATIONID) values ('x5')
END
ELSE IF(@COMPANY = 'Company_name2')
BEGIN
    insert into @tblIL(INVENTLOCATIONID) values ('X0', 'X1','X2','X3','X5','X6','X8','P6','P8')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    insert into @tblIL(INVENTLOCATIONID) values SELECT DISTINCT INVENTLOCATIONID FROM INVENTDIM
END

SELECT INVENTLOCATIONID FROM INVENTDIM INV 
WHERE INV.DATAAREAID = @COMPANY AND INVENTLOCATIONID IS NOT NULL AND WMSLOCATIONID IS NOT NULL AND WMSLOCATIONID <> '' 
AND INV.INVENTLOCATIONID in (select INVENTLOCATIONID from @tblIL)
```